# How to get all windows groups along with their permissions using WMI C#?

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, wmi

I am trying to read

1. All **Groups** of Users in Windows
2. **Permissions** (ACL, DACL etc) on each group.

Here is my code

```
public List<GroupPermissions> GetGroups()
{
    var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");
    var sQuery = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_SecurityDescriptor");
    var secDesc = new List<GroupPermissions>();
    try
    {
        var mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope,sQuery);

        foreach (ManagementObject mObject in mSearcher.Get())
        {
            var sDObj = new GroupPermissions();
            var aceList = new List<ACE>();
            var saceList = new List<ACE>();

            var aceobjs = (ManagementObjectCollection)mObject["DACL"];
            var aceobjsS = (ManagementObjectCollection)mObject["SACL"];
            var gpTt = (ManagementObject)mObject["Group"];
            var ownerTt = (ManagementObject)mObject["Owner"];
            var sids = (UInt16[]) gpTt["SID"];
            var osids= (UInt16[]) ownerTt["SID"];
            var groupTrustee = new Trustee()
                                   {
                                       Domain =Convert.ToString(gpTt["Domain"]),
                                       Name = Convert.ToString(gpTt["Name"]),
                                       SIDString = Convert.ToString(gpTt["SIDString"]),
                                       SidLength = Convert.ToUInt32(gpTt["SidLength"]),
                                       SID = sids
                                   };
            var ownerTrustee = new Trustee()
                                   {
                                       Domain =Convert.ToString(ownerTt["Domain"]),
                                       Name = Convert.ToString(ownerTt["Name"]),
                                       SIDString = Convert.ToString(ownerTt["SIDString"]),
                                       SidLength = Convert.ToUInt32(ownerTt["SidLength"]),
                                       SID = osids
                                   };

            foreach (ManagementObject ace in aceobjs)
            {
                var dTrustee = (ManagementObject)ace["Trustee"];
                var daclSids= (UInt16[]) dTrustee ["SID"];
                var daclTrustee = new Trustee()
                                       {
                                           Domain =Convert.ToString(gpTt["Domain"]),
                                           Name = Convert.ToString(gpTt["Name"]),
                                           SIDString = Convert.ToString(gpTt["SIDString"]),
                                           SidLength = Convert.ToUInt32(gpTt["SidLength"]),
                                           SID = daclSids
                                       };

                aceList.Add(new ACE()
                                {
                                    AccessMask = Convert.ToUInt32(ace["AccessMask"]),
                                    AceFlags = Convert.ToUInt32(ace["AceFlags"]),
                                    GuidInheritedObjectType = Convert.ToString(ace["GuidInheritedObjectType"]),
                                    AceType = Convert.ToUInt32(ace["AceType"]),
                                    GuidObjectType = Convert.ToString(ace["GuidObjectType"]),
                                    Trustee = daclTrustee 

                                });
            }
            foreach (ManagementObject sace in aceobjsS)
            {
                var dTrustee = (ManagementObject)sace["Trustee"];
                var daclSids = (UInt16[])dTrustee["SID"];
                var daclTrustee = new Trustee()
                {
                    Domain = Convert.ToString(gpTt["Domain"]),
                    Name = Convert.ToString(gpTt["Name"]),
                    SIDString = Convert.ToString(gpTt["SIDString"]),
                    SidLength = Convert.ToUInt32(gpTt["SidLength"]),
                    SID = daclSids
                };

                saceList.Add(new ACE()
                {
                    AccessMask = Convert.ToUInt32(sace["AccessMask"]),
                    AceFlags = Convert.ToUInt32(sace["AceFlags"]),
                    GuidInheritedObjectType = Convert.ToString(sace["GuidInheritedObjectType"]),
                    AceType = Convert.ToUInt32(sace["AceType"]),
                    GuidObjectType = Convert.ToString(sace["GuidObjectType"]),
                    Trustee = daclTrustee

                });
            }

            sDObj.ControlFlags = Convert.ToUInt32(mObject["ControlFlags"] ?? 0);
            sDObj.DACL = aceList.ToArray();
            sDObj.Group = groupTrustee;
            sDObj.Owner = ownerTrustee;
            sDObj.SACL = saceList.ToArray();
            secDesc.Add(sDObj);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return secDesc;

}
```

and dependent classes that i have created (in copy of WMI classes)

```
public class GroupPermissions
{
    public UInt32 ControlFlags;
    public ACE[] DACL;
    public Trustee Group;
    public Trustee Owner;
    public ACE[] SACL;
}

public class ACE
{
    public UInt32 AccessMask;
    public UInt32 AceFlags;
    public UInt32 AceType;
    public string GuidInheritedObjectType;
    public string GuidObjectType;
    public Trustee Trustee;
};

public class Trustee
{
    public string Domain;
    public string Name;
    public UInt16[] SID;
    public UInt32 SidLength;
    public string SIDString;
};
```

It returns nothing. The list object is empty. I am definitely doing something wrong. Can some one please help me out?